# Mysql query combine two ordered queries with limit start count

Tags: mysql

I'm new to MySql and I need to append the results of two independently ordered queries, limit the result of the whole thing combined, and return starting at a certain index.

So something like this

1. the first query will result in an ordered list like this

   ```
   a
   b
   c
   ```
2. the second query will result in another ordered list like this

   ```
   1
   2
   3
   ```

Then append the second result after the first like this

```
a
b
c
1
2
3
```

Then only return a certain number of elements and start at a particular index, so for example I only want total 4 return values starting at index 2, the result should be

```
c
1
2
3
```

As you can see, "c" is at index 2 of the appended result, and 4 elements are returned.

Anybody knows how to write this complicated MySQL statement?

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of your problem, you could use a `UNION`

> `UNION` is used to combine the result from multiple `SELECT` statements into a single result set.

Read more [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html)

As for the second part of your problem, you could use `LIMIT`. Read this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492297/how-to-get-all-rows-starting-from-row-x-in-mysql)

Now to combine the both, lets say you have two tables - tbl1 and tbl2 as

```
tbl1                              tbl2
a                                 1
b                                 2
c                                 3
```

You could use a query as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM tbl1 UNION SELECT * FROM tbl2) as t
LIMIT 2, 9430903;
```

The second number in the limit clause is just a very large number. So this query will retrieve all rows from the 3rd row to the last row.

Hope this helps.